# Sklearn PLSRegression predict fails with binary indicator column in X matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently using PLS Regression to predict a 3 column matrix and using the default n_components of 2. I get a value error due to incorrect matrix dimensions when calling the predict function. This only occurs when there is a binary variable column in the X matrix.

#### Reproducible Example 1: Binary independent variable results in predict error

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression

# Create x and y matrix
X_test = np.reshape(np.random.randn(30),(10, 3))
y_test = np.reshape(np.random.randn(30), (10,3))

# Create binary column
t = np.ndarray((10,1))
t[:5,:] = 0
t[5:10,:] = 1
X_test = np.hstack([X_test, t])

# Estimate PLS Regression
pls_reg = PLSRegression(n_components = 2)
pls_reg.fit(y_test, X_test)
pls_reg.predict(X_test)
```

This results in the following sklearn error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_31713/1419766927.py in <module>
     13 pls_reg = PLSRegression(n_components = 2)
     14 pls_reg.fit(y_test, X_test)
---> 15 pls_reg.predict(X_test)

~/Documents/esgpls_scoring/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_decomposition/_pls.py in predict(self, X, copy)
    382         X = check_array(X, copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    383         # Normalize
--> 384         X -= self._x_mean
    385         X /= self._x_std
    386         Ypred = np.dot(X, self.coef_)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,4) (3,) (10,4)
```

#### Reproducible Example 2: Same X matrix removing binary column results in no error

```
# Using same y_test and X_test previously generated
pls_reg = PLSRegression(n_components = 2)
pls_reg.fit(y_test, X_test[:,:3])
pls_reg.predict(X_test[:,:3])
```

#### Summary

Is this an issue with the PLSRegression predict function? Is there a theoretical reason why you shouldn't be using a X matrix with this form? It isn't clear from the error thrown.

I'm running this on sklearn version 0.24.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code. You should replace the line

```
pls_reg.fit(y_test, X_test)
```

with:

```
pls_reg.fit(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Thank you- should have caught that.